# How do I access JSON data passed via AJAX in my django application?

Tags: python, django, json

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Kill Bill",
         "category": "Movie",
         "id": "179403312117362",
         "created_time": "2011-06-21T17:40:15+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "In Search of a Midnight Kiss",
         "category": "Movie",
         "id": "105514816149992",
         "created_time": "2011-03-21T03:59:21+0000"
      },
      ]
}
```

We could use this as sample data.
So if you were to extract "In Search of a Midnight Kiss" from the request.POST variable, how would you do it ?

Comment: If it's in request.POST, access it from there.

Comment: I did request.POST['data'][2]['name'] , it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll come as a string that needs to be desearialized.

```
import json

def some_http_call(request)
   json_string = request.GET.get('http_parameter_key', '')
   json_object = json.loads(json_string)

   data = json_object["data"]
   for x in data:
       print x["name"]
```

Assuming `some_http_call` is your dispatcher and `http_parameter_key` is the name of the parameter where the json string is coming the code above will print all the names in the array of elements contained in the dictionary `data`.

Comment: http_paramter_key is the name of the paramater you use in the form and  yes is that simple. Try it.

Comment: I guess that won't be needed as I'm passing the above JSON data only.

Answer (score 1):

First you deserialize it using `simplejson` or `json`, then you access it as you would any other Python object.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying Ignacio, so can I do something like this -> response = simplejson.something(request.POST) and then response.data.name ?

Comment: JSON objects decode into Python dictionaries, so that would be `response[u'data'][i][u'name']`.

Comment: Awesome, awesome, everything is so much clearer now. Love you guys